# Why is this django form not valid?

Tags: python, django, forms

Why is this form not validating? It is not even calling the `clean()` method.

forms.py:

```
class SingleSampleForm(forms.Form):

    sample_id = forms.CharField(label='Sample ID:')

    class Meta:
        fields = ('sample_id',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SingleSampleForm, self).__init__()

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('sample_id',
            css_class="search-form-label",),
            Submit('submit', 'Search sample', css_class='upload-btn')
        )

        self.helper.form_method = 'POST'


    def clean(self):
        print('CLEAN')
        sample_id = self.cleaned_data['sample_id']
        if sample_id:
            return sample_id
        raise ValidationError('This field is required')
```

views.py:

```
class SampleView(View):

    sample_form = SingleSampleForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        sample_form = self.sample_form()

        self.context = {'sample_form': sample_form,}

        return render(request,
                    'results/single_sample_search.html',
                    self.context)


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        self.sample_form = self.sample_form(request.POST)

        if self.sample_form.is_valid():
            print('Valid')
        else:
            print('not valid')

        self.context = {
                'sample_form': self.sample_form,
            }


        return render(request,
                'results/single_sample_search.html',
                self.context)
```

I don't understand why it is not even calling the `clean()` method. I have another form which is almost identical which validates. When I do `print dir(self.sample_form)` after I have passed the `request.POST` dict it states that `validation=unknown`. Why is this? How do I check the reason it is not validating?

Comment: Are you performing a `POST`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass `*args` and `**kwargs` when you call `super()`:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(SingleSampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

At the moment, calling `__init__` without any `*args` or `**kwargs` is equivalent to calling with `data=None`. The form is unbound, so will never be valid.

Comment: thank you so much kind stranger! have been looking at this for hours and completely overlooked this..

Comment: Sometimes you just need an extra pair of eyes :)